# What is "Change Profile" in the gnome-terminal, and why is it disabled?

Tags: gnome-terminal

In Terminal menu, inside the gnome-terminal, I have the option "Change Profile". What is it for? And why is it disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Profile is just a presets of how your terminal session should behave. You can create a profile for let us say, when working at night by adding some different colors on terminals output, you can use different fonts if you want so etc.

Answer (score 4):

To add a little bit to @Salih Emin answer, if you don't have yet created at least a second profile, there is nothing to switch to, so "Change profile" is disabled.